# (the) project BankABC, BankABC project or the BankABC project?

Tags: grammar, articles

I struggle with proper usage of articles in the following situation: I have a project for a customer, let's call the customer BankABC. Is the following then correct?

> This is the description of the BankABC project. //I guess here BankABC
>   acts like an adjective

or

> This is the description of project BankABC.

Comment: The best version is "_This is the description of the BankABC project._".
"_BankABC project_" is a compound noun, two nouns acting as one.
The second version, although grammatically correct, would refer to "_Project BankABC_" where it is capitalised and the official title.

Comment: @PeterJennings thanks, and the other one cannot be understood as a project with name BankABC? Because I have seen phrases like "on page 4, behind door C" etc. But maybe that works only with items that are somehow grouped in a collection?

Comment: "the BankABC project" is understood to mean "the project involving BankABC" whilst native English speakers would conventionally hear "Project BankABC" as a project title. IMHO The phrase "Project XYZ" is often used for dramatic effect such as "Project Fear" (the title given to one set of arguments by the opposing side in a recent referendum) .

Comment: @PeterJennings Thanks, so normally I would not use: We work on project ABC. But  if there are 3 numbered documents in front of you, I guess it would correct to say "I will look into document 1", right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is generally better:

"This is the description of the BankABC project."

And you're right, the noun is being used like an adjective.  This is called an "adjectival noun," or a "noun adjunct."  See the following for more:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct

But the second version isn't altogether and completely wrong.  As Peter Jennings points out in his comment, project would have to be part of the proper name of the project itself, "Project BankABC."  Perhaps a goverment program teaching bankers how to read?  Lol.  Names like this aren't super common, they're used to sound a little more grand, a little more flamboyant, like something you would see in a James Bond movie, or something a politician would name something grandiose.